# AMPscript triggered send doesn't fire

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, triggered-send

I'm using the following AMPscript to fire a triggered send from a landingpage, but nothing happens – there's actually no Error message when executing the script.

Any ideas?

```
VAR @emailaddr, @ts, @tsDef, @ts_subkey, @ts_sub
SET @emailaddr = "test@testmail.com"
SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
SET @ts_subkey = @emailaddr 

SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", 187)
SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)

SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", @emailaddr)
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @emailaddr)

AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `InvokeCreate` Function. You can look [ampscript API function](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/invokecreate3/) to know more.

Below is the updated code:

```
%%[
VAR @emailaddr, @ts, @tsDef, @ts_subkey, @ts_sub
SET @emailaddr = "test@testmail.com"
SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
SET @ts_subkey = @emailaddr 

SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", 187)
SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)

SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", @emailaddr)
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @emailaddr)

AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)

SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)

]%%
%%=v(@ts_statusCode)=%%
```

**Output**: **OK** -> email sent

**Output**: **error** -> email not sent

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it, but the output %%=v(@ts_statusCode)=%% still keeps empty

Comment: Found the issue, I used this block along with another DEInsert function within %%[ ]%% block. Now I set it in an own one and it was working. Can anyone explain me way it won't work when putting it in the same %%[ ] %% ?

Comment: `%%==%%`  is used to print the output of the function, it accepts the static values. this can also be written inside the HTML tags, whereas `%%[]%%` block is used to write the ampscript logics combined with functions. If you want to output the function inside the `%%[]%%` block then use `output()` function. for output function refer https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/output/#output